# Unity Moving Objects using Input.mousePosition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple paddle that I am trying to move along the X axis using the mouse. Currently it moves but is off by a large margin, relative to where the mouse is.

I think it is due the fact that half my screen is -7.5 and the other half is 7.5

I was wondering if there is any way to correct this problem. As you can see from my  code I am multiplying by 16, which would be the width if the other half was not negative.

I can move the whole screenplay to make it not negative, so I was hoping there was a function

```
Vector3 paddlePos = new Vector3 (0f, this.transform.position.y , -0.25f);
float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition.x / Screen.width * 16;

paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks, -7.5f, 7.5f);

this.transform.position = paddlePos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code -

```
Vector3 paddlePos = new Vector3 (0f, this.transform.position.y , -0.25f);
float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition.x / Screen.width * 16;

paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp((mousePosInBlocks - 7.5f), -7.5f, 7.5f);

this.transform.position = paddlePos;
```

Mathf.clamp function only returns the value inside the minimum and maximum value range. While you need the mousePosInBlocks value to consider the negative and positive screen space.

Comment: This has fixed the position problem, but has now caused a new one, as my paddle can now be dragged off screen ?

Comment: try changing value 16 to 15(=7.5+7.5).

Comment: Cant even compile that : float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition.x / Screen.width * 15(=7.5+7.5);

Comment: Change to 15 only. I gave explanation for 15 as 7.5+7.5=15. :)

Comment: Nope ball paddle can still be dragged of the screen

Comment: Found the solution  : paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp((mousePosInBlocks - 7.5f), -7.5f, 7.5f);

Comment: Nice catch. Updated answer to final solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help